# Has the injection of collagen-producing skin-derived tenocyte-like cells been shown to result in deleterious phenotype instability?

Tags: tendinopathy, injections, tenocyte, collagen

*Wang, Allan W., et al. "[Autologous tenocyte implantation, a novel treatment for partial-thickness rotator cuff tear and tendinopathy in an elite athlete.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3603857/)" BMJ case reports 2013 (2013): bcr2012007899.* voices some phenotype instability concerns regarding the injection of collagen-producing skin-derived tenocyte-like cells, when treating a tendinopathy:

> In the patella tendon, [platelet-rich plasma] and other cell based approaches have been used for the treatment of tendinopathies. In a recent level-1 randomised controlled trial, collagen-producing skin-derived tenocyte-like cells have been shown to be superior regarding recovery time, pain and function compared to plasma injections alone.
>
> Despite these promising results, **instability of the phenotype is a concern as skin-derived cells are non-homologous to tendon tissue**.

Has any medical trial confirmed or infirmed that the injection of collagen-producing skin-derived tenocyte-like cells results in deleterious phenotype instability?

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.